# Import a module works in PyScripter but not in Python Interpreter

Tags: python, import

I am trying to encryt a module (ency0) by replacing readable variables with unreadable variables. The encrypted module (ency1) works in PyScripter but not in Python Interpreter.

```python
# ency0 module:
 a,b = 2, 3
 _,__ = a,b


# ency1 module:
 import ency0
 print 5*_+6*__ 
 # expect result = 28 # 

# In Python Interpreter:
 >>>import ency0
 >>>import ency1
 Traceback <most recent call last>:
   File "<stndin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "ency1.py", line 13, in <module>
     print 5*_ + 6*__ 
 NameError: name '_' is not defined
 >>>
```

In PyScripter I can have a correct result of 28 as long as running ency0 first then ency1 later. If running ency1 only, then I get an error message of name '_' is not defined.

But in Python Interpreter I always have an error message of: name '_' is not defined no matter run ency0 in advance or not.

I belive I missed some very basic statements that always includes in PyScripter by default.

Answer (score 1):

this is an error because you should access the _ as

```
ency0._
```

if you want to use just _ please use

```
from ency0 import *
```

instead of

```
import ency0
```

you may always use dir() to print the list of your local variables.